# How to wrap a container in an image

Tags: html, css

So I have a class, let's call `cont` that will hold a lot of things, including an image.

Now I want to style the image. We can style an image inside a div with `.cont` using:

```
.cont>img {
    ...
}
```

However, in my `cont` div, I want another box to occupy 150px*150px, where the image is 'inside'. To clarify, I want to have a 150px*150px box, that holds an image that may be smaller:

```
    [         ]
    [  [   ]  ]
    [  [img]  ]
    [  [   ]  ]
    [         ]
```

Basically, in common css, this can be done like so:

```
.cont-image {
   width:150px;
   height:150px;
}
```

But that has the disadvantage of having to add the `cont-image` class to every image.

Is this possible to be inherited and styled automagically™? Somehow Like:

```
.cont>img {
   width:150px;
   height:150px;
}
```

(The above obviously doesn't work, because it stretches the image to the dimension, instead of having a 'wrapper' container.

Basically, I want to have an image have a preset size that it gets dropped into. This can be done like so:

```
  <div style="width:150px;height:150px">
    <img src=""></img>
  </div>
```

So that I have a div that is 150*150 and the image with variable size is inside of it. However, I'm looking to do this through styling the image itself only (no outside div):

```
<img style="???" src=""></img>
```

Comment: What result are you trying to achieve? I don't really get what you mean.

Comment: @KilianStinson I have attempted to clarify my question. Please ask if it is still unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried changing to max-width/height?

```
.cont>img {
   max-width:150px;
   max-height:150px;
}
```

There will be no stretching for image.

Comment: To clarify, I want to have a 150px*150px 'container' for every image -> the above css means that the 'container' will only be the size of the image. (it just caps the max dimensions)

Comment: @Secret And that container will be the same size as image. If image is bigger than 150x150, container will be bigger too, so it's same as modifying image itself? Or i do not understand your question then?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this: **http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/pULZA/1/** ?

Using the same markup:

```
<div class="cont">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50" />
</div>
```

Try changing the size of the image in the fiddle. Try making it `http://lorempixel.com/350/350`. Hope that suits your purpose of capping the image size in the inner container.

Now for the CSS:

Using `:after` pseudo-class to generate a *faux-container*. It is actually not a container, but looks like one. This will help you to not change your existing markup.

```
.cont {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    width: 250px; height: 250px;
    line-height: 250px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

.cont > img {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 150px; max-height: 150px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
.cont:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px; left: 50px;
    width: 150px; height: 150px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    background-color: #ddd;
    z-index: -10;
}
```

Making the `z-index` negative, makes it go behind the image and thus appearing as if a container.

Otherwise, the only option you have is to change the markup to have nested divs.

**Update**:

Check this: **http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/pULZA/2/**

As you have said that you want the container to be fixed at 150px, you can use the half of that figure (75px) to calc and position the `:after` content accordingly. Thus even if the `.cont` dimensions change, the image and its frame will always remain in center.

Using CSS `calc`:

```
.cont:after {
    ...
    /*  to calculate center, 
        we halve the width to 75px and subtract it from 50% of parent 
    */
    top: calc(50% - 75px); left: calc(50% - 75px);
    width: 150px; height: 150px;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Nice one! Would have been perfect if it `.cont>img:after` was possible, because this breaks if `.cont width` changes.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<div class="cont">
    <div>
        <img src="http://www.famfamfam.com/lab/icons/silk/icons/application_form.png" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.cont {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: green;
    padding: 25px;
}

.cont > div {
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    background-color: grey;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align: center;
}

.cont img {
    max-width: 150px;
    max-height: 150px;
}
```

If I understood you correctly, this should work for you.